# python writing dictreader to csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.4

I'm using python 2.4 and trying to export the value of the unix last command to a csv file. I cannot figure out how to get it to actually write each line to a csv file, any help would be appreciated!

```
import csv

def check(user,logfile,name):
    logfile.write('********' + name + '*********\n')
    g = subprocess.Popen(["last",user], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = g.communicate()
    reader = csv.DictReader(stdout.splitlines(),
                            delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True,
                            fieldnames=['id', 'pts', 'cpu',
                                        'day', 'month', 'date',
                                        'time', 'dash', 'off',
                                        'loggedin', 'test1', 'test2'])

    writer = csv.writer(open('dict.csv','wb'))
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either use a `csv.DictWriter()` instead (with matching fieldnames), or turn the dictionary row into a sequence:

```
writer.row([value for key, value in sorted(row.items())])
```

would output the values sorted by their key, for example.

Using a `DictWriter` could be as simple as:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(open('dict.csv','wb'), fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
```

which would write the exact same fields, in the same order, as what your `DictReader()` class is expecting.

Comment: You would also need to write the header explicitly as: 
writer.writeheader()
or else the header will not be written.

Comment: @Bolaka: yes, but not every usecase requires a header row. The OP used an explicit `fieldnames` argument to `DictReader` here, which means there is no header row on the input file either.

Comment: true, not every usecase requires a header row. Its just that - writer = csv.DictWriter(open('dict.csv','wb'), fieldnames=reader.fieldnames) - gave me the impression that it would also write out the header. So I think the answer should mention that if someone does want to write the header, add - writer.writeheader()